# Tableview reloadRows(at:) causes incorrect layout of cell contents

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, tableview

I've got a tableview with a bunch of static cells. Inside two of these cells are `UIDatePicker` objects. These two cells aren't normally visible (they have a height of 0) and will only become visible if the user taps on a specific cell. I call `reloadRows(at:)` in order to animate the cell height expansion (and shrinkage for when the cell has to disappear again).

The problem I'm running into here is that this function causes the DatePicker to be displayed incorrectly. While the cell itself gets expanded just fine the DatePicker shows up for 1 second and then fades out for unknown reasons. If I use `tableview.reloadData()` instead of `reloadRows(at:)` the DatePicker shows up but I won't get the smooth expand and shrink animations. I've tried setting `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` on the expanding cell but neither helped.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1, indexPath.row == 2 {
        if showStartDatePicker {
            startDatePicker.isHidden = false
            endDatePicker.isHidden = true
            return 260
        } else {
            startDatePicker.isHidden = true
            return 0
        }
    }else if indexPath.section == 1, indexPath.row == 4 {
        if showEndDatePicker {
            endDatePicker.isHidden = false
            startDatePicker.isHidden = true
            return 260
        } else {
            endDatePicker.isHidden = true
            return 0
        }
    }else if indexPath.section == 2, indexPath.row == 0 {
        // Size of description cell
        return 100
    }

    return 44
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1, indexPath.row == 1 {
        //Start date cell
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        showStartDatePicker = !showStartDatePicker
        showEndDatePicker = false
    }else if indexPath.section == 1, indexPath.row == 3 {
        //End date cell
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        showEndDatePicker = !showEndDatePicker
        showStartDatePicker = false
    }

    var indexPathArray: Array<IndexPath> = []
    if let startDateTimePickerCellIndexpath = tableView.indexPath(for: startDateTimePickerCell) {
        indexPathArray.append(startDateTimePickerCellIndexpath)
    }

    if let endDateTimePickerCellIndexpath = tableView.indexPath(for: endDateTimePickerCell) {
        indexPathArray.append(endDateTimePickerCellIndexpath)
    }

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPathArray, with: .automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: If you create TableViewCell using auto layouts then no need to pass static height just used estimatedRowHeight and rowHeight of table properties. It will help to solve your problem

Comment: @PravinTate I need to be able to hide the cells containing the DatePickers though. How would I go about doing this if I can't manipulate the cell height?

Comment: Create Table cell using Auto layout and link its height constraint in code file. As per your requirement just hide/show Date picker and call cell's layoutIfNeeded() method. 
Instead of passing static cell height just set Table estimateRowHeight  and rowHeight property.